# Printing unique lines

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Is there some better solution for printing unique lines other than a combination of `sort` and `uniq`?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: @gabe Not requiring the entire file to be stored in memory for example.

Comment: Some versions of `sort` (eg. GNU coreutils) use temporary files and external mergesort if the input is too big to fit in RAM. And most other versions have a `-m` option so this can be done explicitly by chunking the input (eg. with `split`), sorting each chunk, and then merging the chunks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To print each identical line only one, in any order:

```
sort -u
```

To print only the unique lines, in any order:

```
sort | uniq -u
```

To print each identical line only once, in the order of their first occurrence: (for each line, print the line if it hasn't been seen yet, then in any case increment the seen counter)

```
awk '!seen[$0] {print}
     {++seen[$0]}'
```

To print only the unique lines, in the order of their first occurrence: (record each line in `seen`, and also in `lines` if it's the first occurrence; at the end of the input, print the lines in order of occurrence but only the ones seen only once)

```
awk '!seen[$0]++ {lines[i++]=$0}
     END {for (i in lines) if (seen[lines[i]]==1) print lines[i]}'
```

Comment: how about `awk '!seen[$0]++ {print}'`?

Comment: Or even shorter `awk '!seen[$0]++'`, since the `{print}` is implied by an empty command.

Comment: `sort -u` worked perfectly. however, `sort | uniq -u` was missing lines !

Comment: @Chris `sort | uniq -u` only prints the unique lines. In other words, it removes _all_ copies of duplicate lines. In contrast, `sort -u` or `sort | uniq` keeps a single copy of duplicate lines.

Answer (score 4):

Some (most?) versions of `sort` have a `-u` flag that does the `uniq` part directly. Might be some line length restrictions depending on the implementation though, but you had those already with plain `sort|uniq`.

Comment: Er?  `sort -u` goes back to V7 at least.

Comment: Hum... I thought I remembered Solaris or AIX not having that. I'm wrong though, they both have it.

Comment: Solaris and AIX have `-u` but also have a 512-character line length restriction.  (Actually, I think somewhere around Solaris 9 Sun upped it to 5120.  GNU still wins, though.)

Comment: @geekosaur: are you sure?  The work done to remove the 512-byte limit on line length in sort was documented in 'Theory and Practice in the Construction of a Working Sort Routine' by J P Linderman, Bell System Technical. Journal, 63, 1827- 1843 (1984).

Answer (score 1):

For the last part of the answer mentioned in : [Printing unique lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/printing-unique-lines/9923#9923) by @Gilles as an answer to this question, I tried to eliminate the need for using two hashes.

This solution is for : To print only the unique lines, in the order of their first occurrence:

`awk '{counter[$0]++}
       END {for (line in counter) if (counter[line]==1) print line}'`

Here, "counter" stores a count of each line that is similar to the one processed earlier. 
At the end, we print only those lines, that have counter value as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Does Perl work for you?  It can keep the lines in the original order, even if the duplicates are not adjacent.  You could also code it in Python, or `awk`.

```
while (<>) {
    print if $lines{$_}++ == 0;
}
```

Which can be shortened to just

```
perl -ne 'print unless $lines{$_}++;'
```

Given input file:

```
abc
def
abc
ghi
abc
def
abc
ghi
jkl
```

It yields the output:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

Comment: Where is $lines getting defined?

Comment: It isn't.  Since there isn't a `use strict;` or `use warnings;` (actually, it is `strict` that is most relevant here), there is no complaint about using `%lines` before it is defined.  If run with strictures, there'd need to be a line `my %lines;` before the loop.  Note, too, that the hash is `%lines`; one element of the hash is referenced using the `$lines{$_}` notation.

Comment: I think the `sort` solutions may be better for large amount of data (the OP was concerned about "storing the entire file in memory"). `sort` will perform an out-of-core sort if the data is larger than the available memory.