# How to print only unique matches from a regular expression?

Tags: grep

Suppose I have a file with the following text:

1. Number_1
2. Number_3
3. Number_1
4. Number_4

How can I use a regexp to print only one time every different *Number_n*?
Using:

```
grep -oE "Number_\w+"
```

Gives me back all the matches:

> Number_1
>
> Number_3
>
> Number_1
>
> Number_4

But I want the following output:

> Number_1
>
> Number_3
>
> Number_4

Comment: Not quite clear.  You just want the first match, from the first matching line?  Or what?

Comment: @user9008, well, it seems your question wasn't interpreted as you meant it to be. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
grep -oE "Number_\w+"  | sort -u
```

Answer (score 2):

(Oh okay, the edit changes the question a bit.)

The easy way to print only one copy of each output line is to pipe through `sort -u` (or `sort | uniq`), though that will obviously sort the output.

Other related solutions here: [Printing unique lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9918/170373)

---

(The answer to what I originally thought the question was:)

To print only the first string that matches the regex, we can use
`grep -m1 ...`:

```
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.
```

If the matches are on different lines, that works directly, but
if you have multiple matching strings on the same line, then with `-o`, they'll all be printed, so add something like `| head -1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' file | sort -u
Number_1
Number_3
Number_4

$ awk '{Arr[$NF]++}END{for(i in Arr)print i}' file
Number_3
Number_4
Number_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ echo Number_1 Number_2 Number_1 | raku -e '.put for lines.comb(/ Number_ \d+ /).unique;'
```

Outputs:

```
Number_1
Number_2
```

Raku implements a `comb` function that takes a regex matcher. Think of `comb` as the opposite of `split`: you define a regex and Raku selects out those elements for you (i.e. breaking around the desired textual elements, quite the opposite of `split`).

Sample Input (from a file):

```
~$ cat file
1. Number_1 
2. Number_3 
3. Number_1 
4. Number_4
```

Sample Output #1 (use regex to drop line_numbers):

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.comb(/ Number_ \d+ /).unique;' file
Number_1
Number_3
Number_4
```

Sample Output #2 (use `<(`…`)>` capture-markers to identify-then-drop the "`Number_`" text):

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.comb(/ Number_ <(\d+)> /).unique;'  file
1
3
4
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using `jq`:

```bash
$ cat file
Number_1

Number_3

Number_1

Number_4
```

```bash
$ jq -n -R -r '[inputs | select(test("^Number_\\d+$"))] | unique[]' file
Number_1
Number_3
Number_4
```

or, with the regular expression given on the command line,

```bash
$ jq -r -R -n --arg re '^Number_\d+$' '[inputs | select(test($re))] | unique[]' file
Number_1
Number_3
Number_4
```

This selects the lines matching the PCRE regular expression `^Number_\d+$`. It then removes any duplicate matches while keeping only the first unique instance of each matching line.